# How to wrap text to next line in an Android TextView?

Tags: android, textview, word-wrap, android-sdk-2.1

I am using following `TextView` to display some data in it:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/notificationText" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:layout_paddingRight="20dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
```

I want to wrap text to next line. How can I do this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

you must set `android:scrollHorizontally="false"` in your xml.

Comment: can one do this during runtime?

Comment: @Ewoks check [setHorizontallyScrolling](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHorizontallyScrolling(boolean))

Comment: the text gets cut instead of going to the next line

Comment: why do we need to do this?

Answer (score 19):

In Some case It works by setting width to 0dp on text views.

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

here is a link to original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2198160).

Answer (score 12):

You could also try

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

in your XML. This worked for me.

Comment: This works. I spent ages trying to fix it using weights and widths. Thankyou!!

Comment: This is for EditText

Comment: This should not be used for TextView, but only for EditText

Answer (score 4):

You need to set

```
 android:minLines="2"
```