# Android TextView is not wrapping text when applying custom font

Tags: android, textview, word-wrap, android-typeface

I have the strangest problem with a TextView. I have a pretty long text (it does not contain new lines so the textview should fit it automatically). A custom typeface is set programmatically. The problem is that the text is cut. I can see the top of the letters on the edge of the view. The left part of the text is cut and it is not visible.

Here is the XML:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="false" />
```

And here is how I apply the font:

```
descriptionText.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "fonts/okolaksRegular.ttf"));
```

Comment: Check this link :) Hope it helps  ... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197744/android-textview-text-not-getting-wrapped

Answer (score 0):

I found what was causing this problem. There was this item in the AppTheme declaration: `<item name="android:height">?android:attr/actionBarSize</item>`

After I removed it, it worked perfectly.