# Android Layout: Wrap two textview

Tags: android, textview

I would like to achieve the following layout

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAA... BBBBBBBBB
```

Where AAAA is a textview (`ellipsize = "end"`) and BBB is a textview as well.
It will never have more than two lines. I just need the first textview to be wrapped around the second sort of.

How should I do that?

[image: Idea in screenshot]

Comment: Do you mean you want BBB to has a full display and AAA wrapped according to the space left after positioning BBB?

Comment: I think I misunderstand you, your AAA is a two line TextView and wrapped in its second line according to the BBB, right? I don't think I can help if the answer is yes.

Comment: Sadly the answer is yes

Comment: I checked this question already... I don't think it is a duplicate

Comment: The question doesn't seem duplicate. The [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197744/android-textview-text-not-getting-wrapped) was about single textview's wrapping. While this post is about wrapping a textview 1 and keeping textview 2 just on its right side. So I have nominated the question for reopening.

Comment: @Stephane do you want to put heading an then content . Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @rup35h I added a screenshot. Does it make more sense?

Comment: @Stephane i got it B content always display full and A will be wrapped..

Comment: Got something worth a look in my answer

Comment: yup I like it I'll try to implement it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Final result**

[image]

**Explanation**

It is **by no means perfect** and will likely need some tweaking for it to fit your needs. I left out the `ellipsize` part to make it more generic, but it would be easy to adapt the code for that. The idea is simple but it took me a few hours (only because its Sunday) to make it work. We calculate how many more characters from the second `TextView` would fit the last line of the first one. Then with that number we add the last line to the second `TextView` with a color matching the background of the container, this is a limitation that could probably be solved somehow yet I can't seem to find it.

With that, we would have the two views with their text aligned, yet they are still not overlapping each-other to allow the wrap effect. So we get the height of the text and add a negative margin to the second one so that they overlap, to ensure that the first `TextView` is on top of the second one we need to call `bringToFront()` to avoid having the text with the same color as the background over the last line of the first one (wow this is getting confusing). It **may not work** good with different fonts and weights (bold for example) since the characters will likely take more space.

I didn't make it a method but it could easily become generic and reusable, just wanted to prove if I could do it or not. Here's the code for anyone and everyone to enjoy and improve upon. The layout is simply a container (a `RelativeLayout` for example) and two textviews with ids `first` and `second`, I've set the text color to red on the second one to make it clearer but it's not necessary.

**Code**

```
    final TextView first = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    final TextView second = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    final ViewGroup container  = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.container);
    final ViewTreeObserver obs = findViewById(R.id.container).getViewTreeObserver();

    obs.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            //Get characters from the first TextView's last line
            String lastLine = first.getText().toString().substring(first.getLayout().getLineStart(first.getLineCount() - 1));

            //Calculate the number of extra characters that will fit in the first one
            int e = 0; //Extra characters
            int lineCount = first.getLineCount();
            while (lineCount == first.getLineCount() && e < second.getText().toString().length() - 1) {
                first.append(second.getText().toString().substring(e, e + 1));
                e++;
            }

            //Remove those characters again to leave the first TextView as it was
            String firstString = first.getText().toString();
            first.setText(firstString.substring(0, firstString.length() - e));

            //Add the last line of the first textview to the second textview
            second.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#F2F2F2'>"+lastLine+"</font>"+second.getText()));

            //add a negative margin to the second textview equal to a line's height
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) second.getLayoutParams();
            params.topMargin = -(int)(first.getLineHeight()+10);
            second.setLayoutParams(params);

            //Make sure first is on top
            first.bringToFront();

            //Remove the listener
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
                container.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                container.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In RelativeLayout make textview AAA normal 2-lines-high textview without ellipsization and make textview BBB with text "... BBBBBBBB" and with non-transparent background so textview AAA will not be visible behind BBB.

Second option is do it programatically - calculate amount of letters and cut that string down if longer than should be.

But none of those 2 "hacks" will work at 100% if you don't use monospace font. Sorry for my english.

---

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="200dp" android:layout_height="70dp">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/aaa"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout="match_parent"
    android:lines="2"
    android:typeface="monospace" />

  <TextView android:id="@+id/bbb"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout="wrap_content"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:lines="1"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You also need to count amount of letters in string for AAA and so in BBB. If sum of those 2 amounts is more than allowed (texts will overlap) add "... " string before BBB string:

```
BBBTextView = (TextView) findViewbyId(R.id.bbb);

int maxLetterCount = 125; // you need to specify this number
String AAAString = " gtgtfd  def e refrfecj gjv jvrji rf wj jiefijr jgfrjf jrf"
String BBBString = "deeded ed e ddd"

if ( (BBBString.length()+BBBString.length()) > maxLetterCount ) {
    BBBString = "... " + BBBString;
}

BBBTextView.setText(BBBString);
```

Comment: I use roboto so it's not monospaced. I like the first idea. What would the code look like?

Answer (score 0):

The most perfect and precise solution could be achieved only due to:   **FontMetrics**
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html 
With this class we can measure characters, strings and so on.

Answer (score -1):

With out using any library.

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AAA"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/BBB"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/BBB"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! it is only one line. What about two lines?

Comment: does your textview exceed to two lines or it is the maximum already.

Comment: 2 lines is the requirement. It can either occupy one or two lines max

Comment: @Stephane: see edited answer above, if you find the answer is helpful to you, please upvote. thanks

Comment: doesn't work... please test
send screenshot if I'm wrong

Comment: @Stephane: please see the new edited code .. :D previously, i forgot to delete singleLine=true that's why it is not working ..

Comment: Your code will create the following output

    AAAAAA
    AAAA..BBBBB

Ok it doens't work in comments, but no text from A will be over the text from B. It won't wrap around... doesn't fit the requirements

Answer (score -2):

You can use html

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p>Any html code</p>"));
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation of how this answers the question