# Text In the textview not wrapping in dialog box

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-dialogfragment

I am using custom dialog box to display some data. i have used gridlayout and this dialog layout is taken in dialogfragment. Following are snaps

[image: First]
[image: second]

as you can see if we click on list dialog box appears but in it's name textview, item name does not get wrap. until now i have used all options answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197744/android-textview-text-not-getting-wrapped) thread.

xml code is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/edit_name"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="2" >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtv_Reg_Name_dialog"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Thanx in advnce..

Comment: show full ur dialog xml...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set `android:scrollHorizontally` in your textview to `true`
It would scroll your textview horizontally when the width of the screen is small to occupy the complete textview..