# Android TextView Text wont wrap on Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-xml

hello i am trying to wrap a textview that has a long text. but when i test it, it just goes beyond the screen. What im trying to do is it will go to the next line if the text is long and it automatically adjust the layout. I am using this in a listview.

i am referring to this old question [Android TextView Text not getting wrapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197744/android-textview-text-not-getting-wrapped), it works on him so i tried to implement it but it wont effect on mine. thanks for answering.

here's my **XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:background="#e6e6e6"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="4dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_reviewer_name"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Reviewer Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_review_details"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Review"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:width="0dip"/>

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE**

here's my listview:

```
<ListView
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="2.0sp"
            android:id="@+id/lv_reviews"
            android:background="#f2f2f2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Now you have two text views here so is it a 50:50  guessing question?

Comment: no its not. that first textview is just a name. the second is the one i need to wrap its text.

Comment: From the xml side there is no such issue is there any specific height that you give from max height for list item?

Comment: post your listview layout and tell me how you are try to change the content

Comment: ill update my question, ill put the listview

Comment: et_write_review.settext("long text here");

Comment: you have to add the text in listitem model and call notifyDataSetChanged() method.

Comment: listview also seems no issue.

Comment: jarvis layout seems good.but the thing is, jarvis can remove unwanted inner linear layout.

Comment: in your xml coding second textview remove width= 0dip and don't use fill_parent in your linear layout instead of fill_parent use match_parent. single linear layout is enough.then mark your answer as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved. it turns out android studio didnt update my changes when i ran my app. i uninstalled the app and then run it again and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `inputType` to auto manage a multiline text.

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/tv_review_details"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Review"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:width="0dip"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
   />
```

Comment: are you trying to setText(..) after the listView has been setup ?

Answer (score 0):

if i use listView or recyclerView, i well put the layout width match parent as mentioned below:

```
<LinearLayout
           <!--change to match_parent-->
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1">
```

try it once, hope this will help you.

Comment: you feel fill_parent is deprecated. so you added this answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Gravity in vertical orientation, you have to use layout_height=0dp & when you are using Gravity in Horizontal orientation then you have to use layout_width=0dp for every child of Linear Layout so that it can resize the layout by itself

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:background="#e6e6e6"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="4dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_reviewer_name"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Reviewer Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_review_details"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Review"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```