# Android: Programmatically added Textview not wrapping text to next line

Tags: android, textview, word-wrap, programmatically-created

I'm kinda sure I'm doing something stupid wrong but here's my problem.

Basically I try to make a history list using cardviews. In these cardviews I have a LinearLayout with a vertical orientation to put all my content for my card.

In this LinearLayout I have another LinearLayout with an orientation Horizontal which holds the title, ... . Below this linearLayout I have a textview which holds the actual string content. This content is quite large and for some kind of reason it doesn't wrap to the next line.

Maybe this is a bit easier to understand the structure:

CardView

_ LinearLayout (vertical)

_ _ LinearLayout (horizontal)

_ _ _ Textview

_ _ TextView (this is the one with the problems)

I set these components programmatically because I don't know how many cards I have to print beforehand.

Here is the code:

XML:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="url.Fragments.History_Fragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/historiekLijst_Layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:text="Historiek"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="25dp"/>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

History_Fragment class:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) historiekView.findViewById(R.id.historiekLijst_Layout);
        CardView card = DynamicComponent_Helper.makeNewCardview(5, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,Gravity.CENTER , 5, 15, getContext());

    TextView title = DynamicComponent_Helper.makeNewTextView(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 5, Gravity.START, Gravity.START, 0, 20, "title",getContext());
                        title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    TextView content= DynamicComponent_Helper.makeNewTextView(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 5, Gravity.START, Gravity.START, 0, 15, "content which is too long and doesn't get wrapped",getContext());

LinearLayout titleLayout = DynamicComponent_Helper.makeNewLinearLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL, getContext());
            LinearLayout cardLayout = DynamicComponent_Helper.makeNewLinearLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, Gravity.START, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, getContext());

            titelLayout.addView(title);
            cardLayout.addView(titleLayout);
            cardLayout.addView(content);
            card.addView(cardLayout);
            linearLayout.addView(card);
```

My componentCreator_helper:

```
public static CardView makeNewCardview(int margin, int gravity,int layoutGravity, int radius, int padding, Context context){
// Initialize a new CardView
        CardView card = new CardView(context);

        // Set the CardView layoutParams
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        params.setMargins(geefDPAlsInt(margin, context), geefDPAlsInt(margin, context), geefDPAlsInt(margin, context), geefDPAlsInt(margin, context));
        params.gravity = layoutGravity;
        card.setLayoutParams(params);
        // Set CardView corner radius
        card.setRadius(geefDPAlsInt(radius, context));

        // Set cardView content padding
        card.setContentPadding(geefDPAlsInt(padding, context), geefDPAlsInt(padding, context), geefDPAlsInt(padding, context), geefDPAlsInt(padding, context));

        // Set a background color for CardView
        card.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

        // Set the CardView maximum elevation
        card.setMaxCardElevation(15);

        // Set CardView elevation
        card.setCardElevation(9);

        return card;

    }
public static LinearLayout makeNewLinearLayout(int width, int length, int gravity, int layoutGravity, int orientation, Context context){
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutLinearParams =
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(geefDPAlsInt(width, context), geefDPAlsInt(length, context));
        layoutLinearParams.gravity = layoutGravity;
        linearLayout.setOrientation(orientation);
        linearLayout.setGravity(gravity);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutLinearParams);

        return linearLayout;
    }
    public static ImageView makeNewImageView(String imageSource, int width, int length, int margin, int gravity, int layoutGravity, int tag, Context context){
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(geefDPAlsInt(width, context), geefDPAlsInt(length, context));
        imageLayout.gravity = layoutGravity;
        imageLayout.setMargins(geefDPAlsInt(margin, context), geefDPAlsInt(margin, context), geefDPAlsInt(margin, context), geefDPAlsInt(margin, context));
        imageLayout.gravity = gravity;
        imageView.setLayoutParams(imageLayout);
        imageView.setImageResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier(imageSource, "drawable", context.getPackageName()));
        imageView.setTag(tag);

        return imageView;
    }
    public static TextView makeNewTextView(int width, int length, int margin, int gravity, int layoutGravity, int tag, int textsize, String tekst, Context context){
        TextView tekstView = new TextView(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutTextParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(geefDPAlsInt(width, context), geefDPAlsInt(length, context));
        layoutTextParams.setMargins(geefDPAlsInt(margin, context), geefDPAlsInt(margin, context), geefDPAlsInt(margin, context), geefDPAlsInt(margin, context));
        layoutTextParams.gravity = layoutGravity;
        tekstView.setLayoutParams(layoutTextParams);
        tekstView.setGravity(gravity);
        tekstView.setText(tekst);
        tekstView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, textsize);
        tekstView.setTag(tag);
        return tekstView;
    }
```

So I have tried a lot of stuff that I found on stackoverflow and else on the internet. A few things that I found a lot but didn't work are:

```
content.setMaxWidth(0) => my cards have no more content and the height becomes WAY to big

content.setWidth(0) => same result
content.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_IME_MULTI_LINE); => no change
content.setSingleLine(false); => no change
content.setMaxLines(10) => no change
content.setHorizontallyScrolling(false); => no change
```

I have tried some of these together as well. I really hope someone could fix this. Oh yea it works on Android 5.1 but not on Android version 7.

If you're still reading at this line than I would like to explicitly thank you for you're time and effort in advance!

Comment: Have you tried setting layout weight to 1 programmatically as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7254966/8762152)?

Comment: I tried this now but It doesn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright for anyone who has the same problem (I doubt it but still) Here is what fiex it for me. I recalculated the Width and Height of my views to dip's with a function (geefIntAsDp which I have written in a different helper). This works fine with normal Integers but you can't use it with wrap_content or match_parent. So all I needed to do was delete this conversion and it worked.